# Exe file corrupted in client and not able to shutdown server

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, network-shares, file-corruption

**Case1:**

I am creating my application exe using Visual studio 2010 in Windows 10 OS. The coding files are in my server PC (Windows Server 2012 R2). I am accessing the coding files from network.

During the debugging my PC was not responding along with the Visual studio. After some time I found that the exe which I was trying to debug (exe created in debug folder of VB project path) is corrupted and the size of this exe was 0 KB. I didn't change any coding, I only changed some reference. I was not able to delete or move this corrupted exe. If I try to delete or rename this exe, my PC gets stuck. I even tried by rebooting my system (To confirm open handle) but the exe was not deleted. A strange thing that even I couldn’t able to connect to my server PC through RDP at the time of this exe corruption.

**Case2:**

While adding the manifest for my VB6 application through NT.exe the command was hanged and I found that the resultant vb6 exe file was corrupt and had 0 KB size. The manifest adding process will be done by a network windows 7 client PC whereas the file is hosted in server path. In this case also I couldn’t move or delete the error file.

In the both cases, server will become non responsive slowly for all users and after few minutes or hours, users cannot access any files from server. This is happening frequently for me in recent days.

**Methods tried:**

Checked for file handle in process explorer –no handles found
Checked for open files –closed but not solved
Restarted PC – not solved
Deleted using command after problem occurred – not working Checked    Antivirus logs –no error 
Event viewer –no error relating to the file or the program found
Disk check and error checking –no error found
Tried to delete in cmd with this command "fsutil reparsepoint delete " – getting error as Access Denied
Changed HDD in server and disk checked.
Used unlocker software – (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/file-unlocker-5db9e3d3) –no file lock found.

**Temp solution found:**

Problem only solved when the server PC was rebooted. But when I tried to reboot/shutdown the server, it was neither leaving me to reboot nor shutdown. So I finally had to reboot the server by hard reboot method using power button.

Is there any way that I can verify why my exe files got corrupted and why it was blocking me from shutting down the server?

**System Specification:**

**Server:**

Operation System: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64 bit

RAM: 8GB RAM Samsung ECC RDIMM for Server x 2 no's

Antivirus: Symantec Endpoint Protection version 12.1.5 Build 5337

HDD Model: Seagate Constellation ES.3-ST1000NM0033 (1TB HDDs)

RAID: 1 and 0

**Client PC (Case1):**

Operation System: Windows 10 Pro

RAM: 4GB Transcend

Antivirus: Symantec Endpoint Protection

HDD: Western Digital 320GB HDD (Model:WD3200AVJS-63B6A0)

**Client PC (Case2):**

Operation System: Windows 7 Pro

RAM: 4GB Transcend

Antivirus: Symantec Endpoint Protection

HDD: 1 TB SATA seagate Internal (ST31000524NS Constellation ES)

Comment: Why do you think those exe files were corrupted? Did they exist in a working version before?

Comment: Yes, the exe was running perfectly before